# Can Tuition Reimbursement impact your raise?

Tags: salary, benefits

The company I work for recently added Tuition Reimbursement.  When it was explained - asking us to think ahead so it can be put in the budget - we were told that using this benefit would decrease our annual merit increase.  For example, if we use the benefit for a semester during the year and it costs the company 5,000, then they will lower our merit increase by .5% to 1%.

Is this common?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't know what your company's policies are, so we can't advise you. I suggest you speak with your manager or the HR department.

Comment: How much would be taken off your raise for taking $5000 in Tuition Reimbursement.

Answer (score 6):

What's uncommon here - at least in my experience - is the honesty and openness that the employer will reduce your raise if you use the tuition reimbursement. I've never seen a company say things like that, even though I've worked for several companies that offered tuition reimbursement.

In my own experience, I have only utilized tuition reimbursement from one employer. I don't think my annual increases were directly affected by my pursuit of my masters degree; however, I can't say that with any certainty. What may have indirectly affected my raises was that I really had to limit my work week to 40 hours to be able to attend classes and keep up on my homework, studies, school papers, etc. Thus, I couldn't work late during crunch times or put in extra hours at work with the hope of being seen as a more valuable employee.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your manager or HR.

Here where I work (in Brazil), it is well known that if there's a tuition reimbursement, there will be no raise during that year.

This may or may not apply for your company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Brazil.